# Multiple google plus buttons on the same page

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Is it possible to have multiple google +1 buttons on the same page without referencing them different to different hrefs?

I can't use this solution:

```
<g:plusone href="the_first_url" size="small" count="false"></g:plusone>
<g:plusone href="the_second_url" size="small" count="false"></g:plusone>
```

Because there simply aren't other sites and I just want have a different title, description and image linking to the same site.

Is there something like the Facebooksharer where you can define this things within the URL? Or nest Itemproperties for different gplus buttons? Or is there anyway to not call the crawler for specified buttons?

Comment: No, that’s not possible. G+ always fetches the info from the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Facebooksharer

You could start with [the Google+ share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share).

If you wanted to do more sophisticated things like add a button to the shared post in the Google+ activity stream, check out [the Interactive Post Button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive).

> not call the crawler for specified buttons

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but the buttons should not affect crawlers. If you want to change the way the shared content appears, make sure to [setup schema on your page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet).